# How to manipulate button position properties?

Tags: matlab, button

I am struggling to adjust a button position. Should not be that hard but somehow I cant figure it out. Any ideas where to add the correct code?

```
button = 'Continue';

while strcmpi(button, 'Continue')

promptMessage = sprintf('Are the results ok?,\nor should the script be stopped?');
    titleBarCaption = 'Continue?';
    button.Position = [100 100 50 20];                    %this line seems to the issue
button = questdlg(promptMessage, titleBarCaption, 'Continue', 'Cancel', 'Continue');

if strcmpi(button, 'Cancel')
break;
end
end
```

Comment: The line `button.Position = ...` tries to adjust the position of `button`,  but at that point `button` is a char vector (defined in the first line), so you get the error

Comment: Please ask a specific programming question. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) _"Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that randomly places a `uibutton` in a `uifigure` upon pressing continue in the `questdlg` prompt. Here the `uibutton` is named `Test_Button` and is independent of the char vector `button`. With the limited details in the question the I'm not sure if you're attempting to change the position of the button in the `questdlg` prompt instead.

```
UI_Figure = uifigure;
UI_Figure.Position = [0 0 500 500];
Test_Button = uibutton('Parent',UI_Figure);

Figure_Width = UI_Figure.Position(3);
Figure_Height = UI_Figure.Position(4);

button = 'Continue';

while strcmpi(button, 'Continue')

promptMessage = sprintf('Are the results ok?,\nor should the script be stopped?');

titleBarCaption = 'Continue?';
Test_Button.Position = [round(rand(1)*Figure_Width) round(rand(1)*Figure_Height) 50 20];                    

%this line seems to the issue
button = questdlg(promptMessage, titleBarCaption, 'Continue', 'Cancel', 'Continue');

if strcmpi(button, 'Cancel')
break;
end

end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me.